# Using react hooks to usestate every second and update DOM only if state has changed

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-hooks

The code below re-renders my JSX every second (1000) only if I add `+ Math.random()` to the `.fromNow()`. Why is this?

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        if(props.isLive) {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("setTimeAgo", props.time, props.time.fromNow())
                setTimeAgo(props.time.fromNow());
            }, 1000)
        }
})
```

I thought the setTimeout function keeps repeating to infinity? so my console.log should be showing in my console even though my DOM is not rerendering?

**UPDATE**: I realize my misconception of setTimeout.. that it just lags the output for 1 second. Trying to figure out how to have the timeAgo update every second, and then rerender the DOM only if timeAgo changes from its previous state.

Realizing all I need to do is change setTimeout to setInterval.. is there anything I'm missing beyond that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout just runs once after a delay interval, what you need is to use `setInterval` to execute a callback every 1000ms. Also call the useEffect on initial render to setup timer and clear it on unmount

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let timer;
    if(props.isLive) {
        timer = setInterval(()=>{
            console.log("setTimeAgo", props.time, props.time.fromNow())
            setTimeAgo(props.time.fromNow());
        }, 1000)
    }, 
    () => {
        if(timer) clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, []); // empty bracket calls the useEffect callback on initial render
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the "," between the if statement and the anonymous function.. should that be "; return" instead?